# Put one part of sentence outside $ math environment

Tags: math-mode, environments

I want the 'assume' written in normal style. So not within the math environment so it becomes italic.

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{1.2}
\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&h(x)=x^4\cdot(2x^2-1)^3 \\
&assume u=2x^2-1 \\
&h(x)=x^4\cdot u^3 \\
&h'(x)=4x^3\cdot u^3+3u^3\cdot u'\cdot x^4
\end{aligned}
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text{assume }` or `\text{assume $u=2x^2-1$}`

Comment: Why don't you align at the equals signs? (`&=` is the key) By the way, `aligned` inside `$..$` is weird, although I've used that construction at some point, may be *you* are looking for `align` environment which doesn't need the dollars around it. Moreover, may be you are looking for `\intertext{assume $u=2x^2-1$}` so that the text *is* part of the original paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Let
\begin{align*}
  h(x) &= x^{4} \cdot (2x^{2} - 1)^{3} \\
  \intertext{and assume that $u = 2x^{2} - 1$. Then}
  h(x) &= x^{4} \cdot u^{3}, \\
  h'(x) &= 4x^{3} \cdot u^{3} + 3u^{3} \cdot u' \cdot x^{4}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]